# add div text to input on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to show on click div text in the given input field - but when I click on the next div then must show prev text and present text on each click. This is my HTML.

```html
<div class="input"><input id="inid" value="s"></div>
```

Comment: Would you like, when you press the `<div class="symbols">`, will the corresponding pressed symbol appear in the input field? and every time you click on a different symbol, is that symbol inserted in the input field? or how exactly ??

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve this using `getElementsByClassName()` to retrieve all div elements and through a loop, attache click event to retrieve the div text and append it to the input value:

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("symbols");

for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ){
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('inid').value += elements[i].innerText
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="input"><input id="inid" value="s"></div>
<div class="slist">
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">☆</span></div>
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">★</span></div>
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">✤</span></div>
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">✪</span></div>
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">✦</span></div>
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">✫</span></div>
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">✷</span></div>
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">✵</span></div>
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">©</span></div>
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">™</span></div>
</div>
```

The following snippet use jQuery approach:

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("symbols");
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.symbols').click(function(){
    $('#inid').val($('#inid').val() + $(this).text())
  })
})
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="input"><input id="inid" value="s"></div>
<div class="slist">
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">☆</span></div>
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">★</span></div>
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">✤</span></div>
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">✪</span></div>
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">✦</span></div>
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">✫</span></div>
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">✷</span></div>
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">✵</span></div>
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">©</span></div>
    <div class="symbols"><span class="face">™</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: woow very quickly nice solution, respect!

Comment: @SwissCodeMen I didn't notice the jQuery tag, do you want this is jQuery?

Comment: It is not for me, but I am amazed at how quickly you got there, it was the same approach as you, but not as quickly: O

Comment: @SwissCodeMen ah sorry but its ok, post your answer I will up vote it :)

Comment: i have add the solution with a different jQuery code than you have. however similar... :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210053/discussion-between-swisscodemen-and-mamoun-othman).

Answer (score 2):

there is a solution with jQuery. similar to that of the user @Ma'moun othman.

```js
$(function () {
    $('.symbols').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('#inid');
        text.val(text.val() + $(this).text());    
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input"><input id="inid" value="s"></div>

        <div class="slist">
            <div class="symbols"><span class="face">☆</span></div>
            <div class="symbols"><span class="face">★</span></div>
            <div class="symbols"><span class="face">✤</span></div>
            <div class="symbols"><span class="face">✪</span></div>
            <div class="symbols"><span class="face">✦</span></div>
            <div class="symbols"><span class="face">✫</span></div>
            <div class="symbols"><span class="face">✷</span></div>
            <div class="symbols"><span class="face">✵</span></div>
            <div class="symbols"><span class="face">©</span></div>
            <div class="symbols"><span class="face">™</span></div>
        </div>
```